# 404 Not Found Error showing when I run wordpress

Tags: errors, 404-error

I setup all things properly means I did all things that need wordpress running with LEMP stack on Ngnix. But when I load localhost/wordpress for test purpose it is giving 404 Error code.

Please suggest me solution.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that your LEMP stack is running, did you try http://localhost/wordpress ? And is the WP install in your LEMP stack's directory that is used by 'localhost'? And did you set up the URLs properly (don't forget the http:// part)?

Comment: Yes I did it all but still not solved

Comment: 404 means it's not there. Can you put a 'hello' html file in the localhost root? And then try to view that? If that doesn't work, then it's your LAMP stack not working. If that does, make sure that mapping to the wordpress folder is set up properly.

Comment: Ok I trying now and let you know